# Running into offset bug when drawing sprites using pixijs

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, pixi.js

I have the map on which I need to draw some amount of hexagons (approximately it will be from 50*50 to 150*150 elements).

When I draw them on the canvas using PIXI, I get really strange behavior: while it's not a lot of elements, the map has been drawn correctly, all the elements on their places. But when the canvas size changed to about 5000px width and height, all the elements are moved top above the screen. Moreover, the click on the element has been handled on the place where it should be.

I've created a pen to demonstrate this: https://codepen.io/cuddlemeister/pen/OdzMBw

Try to change canvasWidth and canvasHeight in the evnironment from
`canvasWidth: 1500,  canvasHeight: 1500` to `canvasWidth: 4500,  canvasHeight: 7500` and you will see the result.

Here's the evnironment object:

```
const environment = {
    size: 60,
    map: {
        rows: 30,
        cols: 30,
    },
  canvasWidth: 1500,
  canvasHeight: 1500
}
```

You will the that all the visible content has been moved in top direction and it depends on the height of the canvas.

There's a logger enabled on click, try to click the elements or the area where they are supposed to be - the click is handled correctly on the place where the element should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the max size that WebGL context can handle. You can check it by logging `app.gl` property.

[image: Context size]

When using not accelereated canvas via "forceCanvas" everything is ok.

I don't think there is any way to bypass this limitation.

Why do you need so big canvas?

Comment: Thank you, you helped really much. I didn't know about this limitation.